# Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation

Tags: c, mergesort

I'm analyzing `Merge Sort` algorithm with *100 000* elements, it was running fine with *10 000* elements. It showing me exception. Here is my code:

```
void Merge(int *array, int leftIndex, int middleIndex, int rightIndex) {
    int *temp = (int *)calloc(rightIndex, sizeof(int));
    int i = leftIndex, j = middleIndex + 1, k = 0;
    while (i <= middleIndex && j <= rightIndex) {
        if (array[i] < array[j]) {
            temp[k++] = array[i++]; // Here it is showing me exception
        } else {
            temp[k++] = array[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i <= middleIndex) {
        temp[k++] = array[i++];
    }
    while (j <= rightIndex) {
        temp[k++] = array[j++];
    }
    for (i = leftIndex, j = 0; i <= rightIndex; i++, j++) {
        array[i] = temp[j];
    }
}

void MergeSort(int *array, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
    if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
        int middleIndex = (leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2;
        MergeSort(array, leftIndex, middleIndex);
        MergeSort(array, (middleIndex + 1), rightIndex);
        Merge(array, leftIndex, middleIndex, rightIndex);
    }
}

void main() {
    for (long size = 10; size <= 100000; size *= 10) {
        int *array = RandomArray(size);
        MergeSort(array, 0, size - 1);
    }
    _getch();
}
```

> Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
> **temp** was 0x1110112. occurred

Comment: what about to use `free` ?

Comment: You never free the memory allocated at `int *temp = (int *) calloc(rightIndex, sizeof(int));`.  Also, there's no need to cast the return value from `calloc()` in C.

Comment: @bruno Yes I forgot that!!

Comment: @Andrew-Henle Yep I forgot that and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
    int *temp = (int *) calloc(rightIndex, sizeof(int));
```

is wrong.

The index range is from `leftIndex` and `rightIndex` with both ends are included, so `rightIndex - leftIndex + 1` elements will be dealt with and this specification of number of elements will lead to lack of elements when `leftIndex` is zero.

Accessing out-of-bounds of buffers will invoke *undefined behavior*, and it seems it happened to work with fewer elements.

The line should be

```
    int *temp = (int *) calloc(rightIndex - leftIndex + 1, sizeof(int));
```

Also you should free the array: add `free(temp);` at the end of the function `Merge`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not obvious: the size allocated for the temporary array is incorrect. Instead of `calloc(rightIndex, sizeof(int));` you should have `calloc(rightIndex - leftIndex + 1, sizeof(int));` In most cases the allocated size will be much too large, which may pose a problem as you never free these temporary arrays, but when `leftIndex` is 0, the allocated block is too short, causing undefined behavior when you store the element at `temp[rightIndex]`.

Undefined behavior may go unnoticed for many cases: storing a value beyond the end of the array may cause a corruption of the `malloc` arena, but the space allocated may have some slack at the end for alignment purposes so this corruption is harmless. For larger blocks (usually > 128KB) `malloc` may map memory as a separate segment, causing this write attempt to fall outside of accessible memory, causing a crash as you experience.

Note also that your mistake is a side effect of the error prone convention of passing `rightIndex` as the index of the last element instead of passing the index once past the end of the slice. This harmful convention is widely taught in programming classes, causing a lot of confusion among students. It requires `+1`/`-1` adjustments in the code which are easy to forget.

Here is a modified version with a more idiomatic C cnvention:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *RandomArray(long size);

void Merge(int *array, int leftIndex, int middleIndex, int rightIndex) {
    int *temp = calloc(rightIndex - leftIndex, sizeof(int));
    int i = leftIndex, j = middleIndex, k = 0;
    while (i < middleIndex && j < rightIndex) {
        if (array[i] <= array[j]) {
            temp[k++] = array[i++];
        } else {
            temp[k++] = array[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < middleIndex) {
        temp[k++] = array[i++];
    }
    /* no need to copy the remaining elements from array[j] */
    for (i = leftIndex, k = 0; i < j; i++) {
        array[i] = temp[k++];
    }
    free(temp);
}

void MergeSort(int *array, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
    if (rightIndex - leftIndex > 1) {
        int middleIndex = leftIndex + (rightIndex - leftIndex) / 2;
        MergeSort(array, leftIndex, middleIndex);
        MergeSort(array, middleIndex, rightIndex);
        Merge(array, leftIndex, middleIndex, rightIndex);
    }
}

int main() {
    for (long size = 10; size <= 100000; size *= 10) {
        int *array = RandomArray(size);
        MergeSort(array, 0, size);
        free(array);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```